# Apply script on firebase succesful authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have this standard script for logging user in. I also wanted to add redirection when the loging in is succesful, but in the current form it will redirect even if there is error. How can I remake the script so that it only works if there are no errors?

```
function login(){
const userLogin = document.getElementById('loginEmail').value;
const userPassword = document.getElementById('loginPassword').value;

firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userLogin, userPassword).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // ...
    window.alert("Error" + errorMessage);
});
window.location.replace('home.html');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `then()`, just like any other promise.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(userLogin, userPassword)
.then(function(user) {
    // do stuff here when sign in succeeds
})
.catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Doug's answer only works when the user actively signs in. When the user reloads the page, their authentication state will be restored, but the `then()` callback does not fire. If you also want to redirect them in that case, you'll want to use an `onAuthStateChanged` listener instead:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    window.location.replace('home.html');
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

This also replaces then `then()` callback that Doug's answer added, but not the `catch()` block you already had, since that handles problems when the user actively signs in.

Also see the [documentation on getting the signed in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).